# Chart Y Range Selection not working VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have created an incredibly complex sheet at this point to do a lot of stuff with charts. I decided I wanted to adjust it so that it will detect how many y series are in the sheet as opposed to a set amount, and then add these y series to a chart. For some reason even though I am using the same format (except not in a For loop) as for the x_series which is working, the y series will not apply to the chart. Supplied is the relevant code.

```
'Create ranges for Y series if they exist

E = 0
EM = Cells(i + 12, 7).Value
Ef = EM - 1
For E = 0 To Ef

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
        Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
        Dim Final_Range As Range

        Set Range1 = .Cells(2, a + 10 + E)
        Set Range2 = .Cells(2, a + 10 + E).End(xlDown)

        Set Final_Range = .Range(Range1.Address & ":" & Range2.Address)
        Final_Range.Select

        .SeriesCollection(E).Values = Final_Range
    End With
Next E
```

To clarify, the EM is attached to a cell that contains the number of columns being used for the chart. Ef is just used because I don't want to include the x series as a Y series and without subtracting 1 from the column number, this would not be possible.

The last step is the one that will not work. I have it select the range just for my benefit of seeing that it is correct when using debugger. The range is operating properly. I also tested having a number in

```
.SeriesCollection().Values=Final_Range
```

Thinking that it may just not like having a variable in the (). This did not work either.

After seeing some comments, I have adjusted the code to the following

```
    E = 0
    EM = Cells(i + 12, 7).Value
    Ef = EM - 1
For E = 0 To Ef

Dim Range1 As Range, Range2 As Range
Dim Final_Range As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
    Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(2, A + 10 + E), .Cells(2, A + 10 + E).End(xlDown))
F = E + 1
    .SeriesCollection(F).Values = "=" & Range1.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)
End With

Next E
```

Comment: You're trying to assign a range to `SeriesCollection(0)` which I don't believe can exist? Try changing your loop to `For E = 1 to Ef`. You're also missing the chart that you're trying to add this to.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is already mentioned in the comment above by @dwirony , if you start loop at `E = 0` then you get `.SeriesCollection(0` and there is no `0`.

Also, you can make your code a lot shorter by using the modified version below:

```
Dim Range1 As Range ' declare outside the Loop

For E = 1 To Ef    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Graphs")
        Set Range1 = .Range(.Cells(2, a + 10 + E), .Cells(2, a + 10 + E).End(xlDown))

        .SeriesCollection(E).Values = "=" & Range1.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)
    End With
Next E
```

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the responses. I have only included the portion of the code that involves inserting the series into a chart. the chart is created earlier in the code but I did not think all of that would be relevant and would probably just be more confusing. I considered that as well and manually put in a 1 but it still did not work. I have updated the code to what you suggested as well and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

After way more time then I should have spent on this... I found that end with should be placed before the line containing

.SeriesCollection(E+1).Values = "=" & Range1.Address(0, 0, xlA1, xlExternal)

This fixed the issue entirely